# Can you actually restrict where programs are executed from on later versions of Windows?

Tags: windows, security

I was looking [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457006.aspx)

Now, it sounds promising to be able to restrict where programs are executed from, making sure they only execute from %PROGFILES% and %WINDIR%, but I have to wonder how enforceable and lock-downable that is to do. Assuming that page is followed, and there are no current vulnerabilities(only for the purposes of my question).

Can you ensure that programs can't be executed from %TEMP%, that programs couldn't just be launched from cmd or start commands, or from within other programs? Basically, are there any ways around this, and if so, how too could you lock them down?

Answer (score 1):

I think Software Restriction Policies, introduced with Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 are a valid instrument to prevent unwanted programs from running.

If the Path rules you describe are not secure enough in your opinion, you could always add hash rules (cryptographic "fingerprints" of the executables that remain the same regardless of the file name or location.) and certificates.

The only way (that I know) to bypass Software Restriction Policies in Windows XP, is using a secondary logon account (start with "Run As").

Comment: Software Restriction Policies works very well, and I can't believe more people don't use it. Combined w/ keeping users running as limited user accounts you can stop most "end running" of the IT department w/ respect to user-"installed" software. Using it in a "default permit" manner w/ hash rules is silly and easy to bypass, but using it in a "default deny" manner is quite powerful. I thought I'd try it with digital signatures sometime, but we've ended up never needing it. Path rules and limited user accounts have been enough. Give it a try in a lab setting-- you'll like it.

Comment: If I could give a +2 here I would. You want Software Restriction Policies. It's good stuff.

Comment: If you have Win7 Enterprise or Ultimate SKUs available in your environment you want to use AppLocker instead.

Answer (score 1):

Coming in Windows 7 Enterprise & Server 2008 R2:  [AppLocker](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/enterprise/products/applocker.aspx)

I saw a demo of this at a recent TechNet Conference.  You can restrict / allow based on the folowing characteristics of the executable:

-Path Rules

-Hash Rules

-Publisher Rules

Using the above rules together, you can *"ensure that programs can't be executed from %TEMP%, that programs couldn't just be launched from cmd or start commands, or from within other programs?"*

[More info here.](http://4sysops.com/archives/review-windows-7-applocker-part-1-overview/)

Anapologetos

Comment: This sounds like a fancy rebranding of what is already possible, based on the link I provided, which doesnt necessarily stop the workarounds I mentioned

Comment: Bill, with Hash Rules, as mentioned mine, and in another answer, it does not matter where the exe is run, what privilege level, etc.  If it matches a "restricted" hashed exe, it will not run.

Comment: What you seem to be talking about is a blacklist of hashed exe's, which is impossible. I'm asking if it is possible to launch an untrusted exe from a trusted exe(cmd.exe) or via rundll or such

Comment: Bill, I was not meaning neccesarily a restricted hash blacklist, though this is possible (and would be useful in certain environments). "AppLocker’s management tools are optimized towards creating an “allow list” of applications i.e. the list of applications that are allowed to run. Applications not on the allow list are blocked by the system."  You create policies, "using publisher rules for signed binaries and hash rules for any unsigned binaries it might encounter." It doesnt matter where or how it is run, because Applocker sits at such a low level.
Source:  http://tinyurl.com/otdo8a

Comment: Anapologetos, that does seem quite similar to what is already available in the link I posted, and does not show why it would not be possible to get around it by simply launching via the start command, or calling the program via a dll or such

Comment: First off, yes, Applocker is a facelift + more features to SRP.
Secondly, I'm not sure how else to explain it.  Running an exe either the start command or another way still dumps you to one specific place: the Applocker subsystem.  So no matter if you start cmd, type "ipconfig" (which forks a process to run ipconfig) or you actually dblclick the ipconfig exe, the execution runtime will still go through the Appblocker subsystem-
There is no way run the exe that won't run it through the appblocker subsystem (unless of course you have a rootkit that redirects execution...)

Answer (score 0):

A public lab at our university apparently uses this policy in a Vista environment, but it doesn't seem to be completely restricted. I'm not sure what the rules are. Portable putty works from my desktop, for instance.
One time I wanted to run the simple lame executable from my desktop to encode a wave file and it wouldn't run.

Answer (score 0):

I am personally not a big fan, but McAfee Enterprise 8.5i (and prob others) will allow you to easily create custom rules that restrict where .exe's fire off from.

Comment: In my experience such commercial tools are easily bypassed, e.g. by simply running the program from within cmd.exe

Comment: @Bill Gray. That's not case with Software Restriction Policies or AppLocker (the re-do of SFP for Win7). AppLocker even has a facility to control what DLLs will execute as well as script execution for Batch, WSH and PowerShell engines. You can't bypass the execution policy. AppLocker is muuuuuuuch easier to configure than SFP. The default rulesets are pretty close to what you would want.